# Change back button label in navigation bar using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigation controller, with 3 view controllers.

Nav Ctrller -> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3

Say I want the 'Back' button on VC2 and VC3 to read 'Previous' instead. In VC1, I selected/highlighted the nav bar item from Storyboard and changed the Back Button property to 'Previous'.

Now VC2 back button says 'Previous', but the back button on VC3 still says 'Back'. I thought I need to make the same change for nav bar item in VC2, but there is no nav bar item to select. I guess nav bar item shows up only in root VC?

Currently I am changing the back button label on VC3 by code. Is there no option to change the back button label on VC3 using Storyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: look like you are giving an assignment to someone, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried literally everything except drag a navigation item to VC3 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag a navigation item to your VC3

[image: Storyboard]